# realizar consultar con una condicion en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure, select

tengo una tabla **persona** y una **sesion** y en la tabla **sesion** tengo la columna *categoria*, entonces quiero hacer una consulta que ignore las personas que sean *admin* he probado estos codigos y no he obtenido el resultado que quiero.

```
create procedure listarUsuarios()
begin
select 
persona.nombres as nombres,
persona.apellidos as apellidos,
persona.correo as correo,
persona.codigo as codigo,
sesion.categoria as categoria
from persona, sesion
where persona.correo = sesion.correo and sesion.categoria not like 'admin%';
end
//
```

Comment: te deje la respuesta actualizada incluyendo como crear y mandar llamar el PA saludos

Comment: Si te sirvió agradecería la marques como respuesta aceptada saludos

Comment: ps si, era con joins.no habia visto tu respuesta porque no llegaba a ningun lado investigando, asi que se me dio por utilizar join y me sirvio y no volvi a entrar a la pagina.

Comment: TE agradeceria dado eso la marques por favor

Comment: y como lo marco?

Comment: A lado de la pregunta que hiciste aparece para aceptar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

al margen de que deseas crear un stored procedure te comento que lo mejor para consultas multi tabla es usar JOINS pues simplificarán la carga de trabajo al momento de las consultas; en las siguientes líneas te darás cuenta que en lugar de pasar el valor del campo como cadena de texto es decir "admin", use el id que identifica a la categoria de admins

```
SELECT usuarios.*, categorias.* FROM usuarios
JOIN categorias
ON  usuarios.id_categoria = categorias.id
WHERE usuarios.id_categoria = 1;
```

Ahora si lo que quieres son todos los usuarios que no sean admins, pasale solamente el id que identifique a esa categoria o rol o como lo hayas nombrado en tu tabla

En mi ejemplo el id 1 es para admins y el id 2 es para invitados solo es cuestión de cambiar esos valores

//ACTUALIZACIÓN

Para poder crear tu PA, sigue mi ejemplo siguiente y luego mandalo a llamar

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE datos()
BEGIN
   SELECT usuarios.*, categorias.* FROM usuarios
JOIN categorias
ON  usuarios.id_categoria = categorias.id
WHERE usuarios.id_categoria = 1;
END $$


call datos();
```

Como puedes notar si solo haces el PA no arrojará nada, pero si ejecutas **call** seguido del nombre del PA te mostrará su funcionalidad

Al final si deseas saber o recordar los nombres de los PA que creaste, solo ejecuta el siguiente comando **Importante no alteres los que no creaste**

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS;
```

Comment: gracias, ya lo habia arreglado con los joins.

Answer (score 2):

Con este codigo te devuelve todas las personas que no son admin:

```
select 
persona.nombres as nombres,
persona.apellidos as apellidos,
persona.correo as correo,
persona.codigo as codigo,
sesion.categoria as categoria
from persona, sesion
where persona.correo = sesion.correo and sesion.categoria != "admin";
```

Comment: no sivio eso, ya lo habia intentado con comillas simples.

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y me retorna exactamente como lo necesitas, que error te sale?

Comment: ninguno, me salen todas las personas y tambien me salen los admin, eso es lo que pasa

Comment: Como tienes guardado los "admin" , es decir tienen algun otro caracter o solo "admin".

Comment: no, era con joins. deje de responderte porque no llegaba a ningun lado, asi que se me dio por utilizar join y me sirvio y no volvi a entrar a la pagina.